# How to convert between different instantiations of the same variadic template?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion, variadic-templates

Assume we have a data structure Foo that maintains a set of elements. It should be possible to associate attributes with the elements as needed. The attributes should be stored in a separate vector each. We implement this by means of variadic templates:

```
#include <vector>

template <typename ...Attrs>
struct Foo : public Attrs... {
  Foo(int n = 0) {
    using PackExpansionT = int[];
    PackExpansionT{0, (Attrs::values.resize(n), 0)...};
  }
};

struct AttrA { std::vector<int>    values; };
struct AttrB { std::vector<float>  values; };
struct AttrC { std::vector<double> values; };

int main() {
  Foo<AttrA, AttrB> foo; // Maintains set of elements with two attributes each.
};
```

Now, I want a conversion operator with the following semantics:

```
  Foo<AttrB, AttrC> bar = foo; // bar.AttrB::values should be a copy of foo.AttrB::values.
```

This is only an example. In general, the conversion operator should be able to convert a `Foo` with arbitrary attributes into another Foo with arbitrary attributes. Attributes associated with both `Foo`s should be copied. Attributes not associated with both can be left defaulted. However, I have no idea how to implement it.

```
  template <typename ...OthersAttrs>
  operator Foo<OthersAttrs...>() const {
    // ...?
  }
```

Comment: What do you do about attributes that associated with the target but not the source?

Comment: Not important for now. Perhaps their value is set to some default, perhaps their value is simply undefined.

Comment: @user1494080 It's pretty important: what is it you want `bar` to be after the copy initialization from `foo`?

Comment: @Barry Well... as I said: Attributes associated with both should be copied. Attributes associated only with bar may be undefined or set to a default value. I don't care. What is important to me is that all attributes associated with both are copied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can just make a bunch of independent decisions. First, let's add a constructor so that we can construct `Foo` from its attribute constituents:

```
Foo(Attrs const&... attrs)
: Attrs(attrs)...
{ }
```

Next, for each attribute in `Others`, we will either downcast `this` to the appropriate type if possible or return a default-constructed one otherwise:

```
template <typename... Others>
operator Foo<Others...>() const {
    return {get_attr<Others>(this)...};
}
```

where:

```
template <class T>
T const& get_attr(T const* v) const {
    return *v;
}

template <class T>
T get_attr(...) const {
    return T{};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An outline I can think of:

```
template <typename ...OthersAttrs>
operator Foo<OthersAttrs...>() const
{
    Foo<OthersAttrs...> rv(GetNSomehow());
    (int[]){(CopyAttr<Attrs>(&rv), 0)...};
    return rv;
}

template<typename Attr>
void CopyAttr(Attr *rv) const // Overload A
{
    rv->values = ((const Attr*)this)->values;
}

template<typename Attr>
void CopyAttr(...) const // Overload B
{

}
```

The trick here is to go attribute by attribute.
If `rv` has the attribute the first overload will be chosen and it will be copied.
Otherwise the second overload would be chosen that will do nothing.